# Peskin-Schroeder, Unitarity of the S matrix, eq 9.61

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, unitarity, s-matrix-theory

I have a question regarding a derivation in Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book. On page 298, he is discussing a method for defining a gauge invariant S matrix. He does this by defining projection operators $P_0$ that project general particle states into gauge invariant states, and then defining an S matrix as $$S = P_0S_{FP}P_0,\tag{9.59}$$ where $S_{FP}$ is the general S matrix between general states. This S matrix is therefore by definition gauge invariant, but now its unitarity can be questioned. He "proves" that this new $S$ matrix is unitary first by stating that $$\sum_{i=1,2}\epsilon^\ast_{i\mu}\epsilon_{i\nu}\mathcal{M}^\mu\mathcal{M}^{\ast\nu} = -g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{M}^\mu\mathcal{M}^{\ast\nu},\tag{9.60}$$ where the sum runs over only transverse polarization states. He also points out that this identity holds true even if the two amplitudes are distinct. He claims that this is the exact information we need to prove the following $$SS^\dagger = P_0S_{FP}P_0S_{FP}^\dagger P_0 = P_0S_{FP}S_{FP}^\dagger P_0.\tag{9.61}$$ From here it is easy to see that, on the subspace of gauge invariant states, this is equal to the identity, because the $S_{FP}$ matix is unitary. However, I do not see the relation between these two equations at all, or how he uses the first to justify the second step in the second equation. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It is possible he is saying that, because of equation 9.60, states with longitudinal and timelike polarizations can be included or discarded without physical result because their Feynman amplitudes cancel one another.Therefore, one can insert a complete set of states between the two P operators in 9.61, and remove the P operators because projecting onto the set of gauge invariant states has no effect because of 9.60. Just a guess

Comment: https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~mspannow/files/SkriptQFT_Weigand.pdf#page=137

https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/FrancescoHautmann/Ralhep/ralss10_p.pdf#page=33

Comment: I think that nickodel has the right answer. Before I saw his post, I gave a similar reply to the same question on this forum : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/696130/proof-of-unitarity-of-gauge-invariant-s-matrix-in-peskin-and-schroeder